# g++:error: `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, python, g++, opencv

I run a program  like this:

```
g++ begueradj.cpp -o begueradj`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

I want to run the above command line from a Python file **test.py**:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["g++", "begueradj.cpp", "-o", "begueradj","`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`"])
```

However, I get this error:

```
g++:error: `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` No such file or directory
```

How to resolve this ?

**P.S.**

Note that the command works fine on Terminal.

Comment: Look at the documentation of [`subprocess.call`](//docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call). The [FAQ of that module](//docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) has an entry on the relation between the first argument and the named function argument `shell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python cannot perform a shell's job and do command substitution. You would have to perform the command substitution yourself, or wrap the whole thing using `sh -c` or `bash -c`:

For example, using [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to get the output of the `pkgconfig` command:

```
import subprocess
pkg_config_flags = subprocess.check_output(['pkg-config', '--cflags', '--libs', 'opencv'], universal_newlines=True).strip().split()
subprocess.call(["g++", "begueradj.cpp", "-o", "begueradj"] + pkg_config_flags])
```

Or using `sh -c`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["sh", "-c", "g++ begueradj.cpp -o begueradj `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`"])
```

This last method can be simplified if you use [`shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations):

```
subprocess.call("g++ begueradj.cpp -o begueradj `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`", shell=True)
```